# Java web service client not decoding base64

Tags: c#, java, web-services, iis

I'm currently trying to implement a WS client in java but I have the following problem:

The server is running in IIS 7.5 and was implemented with c#. It is sending a base64Binary string (which I believe it is supposed to since the original data was a byte array) but on the java side, all I get is an object of class B.

How can I get a byte array back from that object?

Thanks

Comment: So you are taking an object in C#, serializing it via base62Binary, sending it to a java app and then attempting to deserialize it? (Pasting code would help immensely!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a object of type array of byte (byte[])

```
System.out.println("class=" + byte[].getClass());
System.out.println("class=" + byte[].getClass().getName());
```

produces an output of

```
class=class [B
class=[B
```

If this matches your output, then just cast the object into a byte[]

```
(byte[]) array;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `Class [B`? In that case all you need is to cast:

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[]) obj;
```